# in_category() works in single.php but not in page.php?

Tags: categories, php, customization, pages, single

I'm using [`in_category(array)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) inside The Loop to detect whether a post is categorised into the Discussion category (or has one of a couple of slugs). This works beautifully on `single.php` but doesn't even seem to be evaluated when used inside `page.php`?

FWIW, here's my code:

```
<?php if ( in_category( array( 'Discussions', 'discussion', 'discussion-article' ) )) :?>
<p id="discussions-prepended"><em>This is an article from our Discussions series - read more in the <a href="/discussions">Discussions section</a>.</em></p>
<?php endif;?>
```

On the borked page.php instance, I've also tried

```
<?php elseif:?>
<p>This post does not meet the category criteria.</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

but that doesn't show either leading me to believe the code's not being evaluated. This code snippet was, in both instances, inserted directly before `<?php the_content(''); ?>` (`the_content()` in single.php); it just doesn't eval or show up in page.php. Intentional behaviour or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Did you enable categories for pages somehow then? It's not native functionality for pages to have categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have added the functionality with a plugin or custom code, Pages are not placed in Categories. Pages are organized with Parent Pages and Children Pages. This is why (I suspect) in_category() does not work in page.php

The following code in functions.php will add categories to Pages.

```
/**
*   Add categories to Pages.
*   from http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-tags-and-categories-to-your-wordpress-page
*/ 

    function add_custom_tags_box() {
        add_meta_box(   'categorydiv', __('Categories'), 'post_categories_meta_box', 
                'page', 'side', 'low'); 
       register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Afaik you'd only have `add_theme_support()` for pages.

Comment: Ah, so simple when one realises what one is doing wrong! Thanks for your patient explanation of why what I was doing would never work ;-) - I'll experiment with that code when I have a free few minutes.